# How to make StackPane with a MediaView fill a BorderPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

Hey all I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with my code. I am building a very simple media player. I have a BorderPane as the root scene. The top node is a Menu and the bottom is the StackPane. I have a StackPane that holds a MediaView and a toolbar. I want to make it so whenever the user opens up a new file the StackPane will resize to the MediaViews's new width. The height is fixed. The way I understand how BorderPane defines its size (from reading the docs) is the children's pref sizes. The StackPane defines its size from its children as well. Here is what the docs say: 
Resizable Range

A stackpane's parent will resize the stackpane within the stackpane's resizable range during layout. By default the stackpane computes this range based on its content as outlined in the table below.

---

minimum:

width: left/right insets plus the largest of the children's min widths.

height: top/bottom insets plus the largest of the children's min heights.

preferred:

width: left/right insets plus the largest of the children's pref widths.

height: top/bottom insets plus the largest of the children's pref heights.

---

The issue is that you can't set the min, max, or pref size on MediaView, only the fit height or width. How could I go about computing the size so it fits correctly?
Here is my code how it is currently

```
// Initially set bottom to an empty pane
nullPane.setPrefSize(600,400);
mainPane.setTop(menuBar);
mainPane.setBottom(nullPane);
```

---

```
stackPane.getChildren().addAll(mediaView, toolBar);
mediaView.setFitHeight(mediaHeight); // mediaHeight = 500
mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);
mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
mainPane.getChildren().remove(nullPane);
mainPane.setBottom(stackPane);
```

---

[A screenshot of how the pane is initializing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF0GE.jpg)

[A screenshot of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp1fG.jpg)

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the BorderPane have anything in its center?  If not, you should place the StackPane in the center, not the bottom.